# No Launcher Activity Found. The launch will only sync the application package on the device

Tags: java, android

I'm having an error in launching my test application, I'm a newbie on android development I hope you guys can help me.

Herewith is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks.MENUA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I am getting following error:

> [2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] Android Launch! [2013-11-11
>   22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] adb is running normally. [2013-11-11 22:59:16 -
>   WeirdGeeks] No Launcher activity found! [2013-11-11 22:59:16 -
>   WeirdGeeks] The launch will only sync the application package on the
>   device!

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error. Can you share your log cat.

Comment: It may be because you does not mention the proper class name for launcher activity

Comment: [2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] ------------------------------
[2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] Android Launch!
[2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-11-11 22:59:16 - WeirdGeeks] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Comment: how can i mention it in a proper way? i'm a newbie i just follow what's on the video tutorial. please do help me.

Comment: No Problem. Just clean and run your project before that make sure that MainActivity in com.jhaydev.weirdgeeks package

Comment: ok i will try to clean my project and then run.  will update you in a moment thanks Subramanian.

Comment: I did clean my project but then same things happen... it shows the same error on logcat/console. Is there any way other than that?

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace This line in your code:

```
 <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thanks Subramanian R. It works fine. thanks for the big help. :) May God Bless you always.